# passing object to a job apscheduler as an argument for the function

Tags: python-3.x, apscheduler

I try to pass an object as an argument to a job function with apscheduler.
That's fine but in my case I'd like to change one of its value and use the updated value when the job is triggered.
Here is my sample code

```
import time
import sqlalchemy
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.jobstores.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyJobStore


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.state = kwargs.get('state', "")


jobstores = {
    'default': SQLAlchemyJobStore(url='sqlite:///sched.db', tablename='apscheduler_jobs')
}

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.configure(timezone='Europe/Paris')
scheduler.add_jobstore(jobstores['default'], 'default')


def myFunction(_internals):
    print("- in job")
    print(_internals.__dict__)
    print(".")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    scheduler.start()
    myInstance = MyClass(state="off")
    print(myInstance.__dict__)
    j1 = scheduler.add_job(myFunction, trigger='cron', args=[myInstance],  second='*/10', max_instances=10, jobstore='default', srv_id="blablabla-x6548710")
    try:
        # This is here to simulate application activity (which keeps the main thread alive).
        while True:
            time.sleep(2)
            myInstance.__setattr__("state", "running")
            print(myInstance.__dict__)
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        print('exit')
        scheduler.shutdown()
```

Here is what I expect:

```
{'state': 'running'}
{'state': 'running'}
{'state': 'running'}
{'state': 'running'}
{'state': 'running'}
in job
{'state': 'running'}
.
{'state': 'running'}
```

But instead I have:

```
{'state': 'running'}
{'state': 'running'}
{'state': 'running'}
{'state': 'running'}
{'state': 'running'}
in job
{'state': 'off'}
.
{'state': 'running'}
```

Is there a way to have the same value in the while loop and the job at the time this one is triggered ?

Thank you boys and girls

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that myInstance in the job was a totaly different object.
Thus it wasn't affected by any change made in the loop.
I used another strategy : 
using memcached to communicate between the loop and the scheduled job.
Still open to any other suggestion.